# How to create a protected directory with Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing a mobile application using Phonegap (Apache Cordova) ver. 3.3.0 for both Android platform and iOS.

This application should be able to create a directory in the mobile device, and access to this to save some files that I have downloaded from external urls.

The application, now, creates correctly the dir, and can access to it to save files.
The problem is that I want to make it a "protected" directory: the directort should be opened only pressing a button in my app, but inaccessible from anywhere else.

How can I realize this?

This is my code, for the creation of the directory.

```
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        }

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            console.log(fileSystem.name);
            console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
            var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
            directoryEntry.getDirectory("myDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail);
        }

        function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
            console.log(parent);
            //parent.fullPath = path to dir in smartphone
            window.localStorage.setItem("directory_path",parent.fullPath);
        }

        function onDirectoryFail(error) {
            alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
        }

        function fail(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is impossible in cordova or any other language!

If you wish to accomplish something like that- use sqlite to create folder structure ant save data files there.

Comment: I know, but I was asked the realization of this functionality without the use of internet in the app, so I thought you could set permissions to folders.

Comment: how would file system differentiate between your app and folder browser app, launched by the same user?

You can do app without internet, cordova supports sqlite.